# how to compare the values present in excel table and value taken by the user in java programming

Tags: java, jdbc

I have used if loop to compare the values present in table and the value entered from the user, but in the code its not entering to if loop rather it is entering to else loop, i need the suggestion for the problem.

Here is the code :

public  void idExists(String SkillID) {

```
    try{
        Connection conn = dbconnect();
        conn.setReadOnly(false);
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        String  skilid= "Select [Skill ID]from [Skill Master$]";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(skilid);

        while(rs.next()){

              String Skill = rs.getString("Skill ID");
                          System.out.println(SkillID);
        }
            if (SkillID==Skill) {
                System.out.println("the skill id  exist");   
                } 
            else { 
                System.out.println("the skill id doesnt exist");    
                    }   

            endConnect();


    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Got an exception in idexist");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());

        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Seems odd that your db field name has a space in it.  Not sure if that's your problem though.  Also could be that SkiiID and Skill are different data types (int vs string).  Use your debugger :)

Comment: Yes your right, it was comparing two diff data types..

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing string value by reference.
Since your variable refer to two different `String` instances with the same value, the condition is false.

You should compare strings using the `equals` method.

Also, you probably want to put the `if` inside the loop.

Finally, you should replace all of that code with a (**parameterized**!) `WHERE` clause.

Comment: while(rs.next()){ Skill = rs.getString("Skill ID"); if (SkillID.equals(Skill)) { System.out.println("the skill id exist"); } else { System.out.println("the skill id doesnt exist"); } }                                                       i modifies the code as above, but still the problem is not resolved